# Excel functionality without Excel

Tags: windows, excel, ms-office

Currently we have a system which we paid for that pushes information into Excel through a plugin and only into Excel. This is the way the product was designed. In a spreadsheet you enter a command which then pulls the appropriate data.

I wrote a few lines of code to save the data from excel into a SQL database and then push this information onto a webpage so it can be easily viewed.

The problem with this is that it requires Excel to be open 24/7. Every so often Excel will hiccup causing information to stop updating. This is easily fixed by restarting the Excel spreadsheet, but is tedious.

My question: is there any API which allows me to mimic Excel without having Excel open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research on this it has become clear to me that there is no Excel API from Microsoft to allow access to Excel without excel.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a spreadsheet component that can be embedded in an application.  You can find a list here:

http://www.devdirect.com/all/SPREADSHEET_PCAT_1977.aspx